# match expression falling through?

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

**Update:** this is an old bug [solved](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26251#event-770023973) in 1.12

---

Here is some contrived but simple pattern matching example [(demo)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20%27a%27%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20match%20x%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27a%27...%27b%27%20if%20false%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22one%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27a%27%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22two%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27a%27...%27b%27%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22three%22%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20panic!%28%22what%3F%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A&version=stable):

```
fn main() {
    let x = 'a';

    match x {
            'a'...'b' if false => {
                println!("one");
            },

            'a' => {
                println!("two");
            },

            'a'...'b' => {
                println!("three");
            },

            _ => panic!("what?")
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get `three` as output. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the second branch match first?

Comment: Oooh, that looks like a bug. If you comment out *either* match arm with a `...`, it does match "two", even if you comment out the match arm **after** the "two". Pure speculation, I wonder if there's some incorrect optimization that is coalescing the two ranges together and making them fire first. Mmm, yeah, if you change the first range to `'a'...'c'`, then 
"two" matches as well...

Comment: I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26251).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the LLVM IR in Debug, it is already flawed, so this is definitely a bug in `rustc`; we'll use the curated IR below to check what's going on.

So, `%x` is assigned 'a' (97 in ASCII), and `%10` is assigned the result of `x >= 'a' and x <= 'b'`; if this is true, we go to `match_case`, otherwise to `compare_next`. `match_case` redirect to `cond`, which redirects to `case_body2` which prints `"three"`.

In theory, we would have wanted to go to `case_body1` (printing `"two"`), from `cond7`, from `match_case4`, from `compare_next`. But `compare_next` is only reached if `x` is not in `['a', 'b']` according to the IR.

This clearly looks like a bug.

```
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define internal void @_ZN4main20h4f7b0d7962de19d8eaaE() unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  %x = alloca i32
  ; [...]
  store i32 97, i32* %x
  %7 = load i32* %x, !range !0
  %8 = icmp uge i32 %7, 97
  %9 = icmp ule i32 %7, 98
  %10 = and i1 %8, %9
  br i1 %10, label %match_case, label %compare_next

case_body:                                        ; preds = %next6, %next
  ; println!("one")
  br label %case_body8

case_body1:                                       ; preds = %cond7
  ; println!("two")
  br label %case_body10

case_body2:                                       ; preds = %cond
  ; println!("three")
  br label %case_body15

case_body3:                                       ; preds = %match_else
  ; panic!("what")
  unreachable

match_else:                                       ; preds = %compare_next5
  br label %case_body3

match_case:                                       ; preds = %entry-block
  br i1 true, label %cond, label %next

compare_next:                                     ; preds = %entry-block
  %16 = icmp eq i32 %7, 97
  br i1 %16, label %match_case4, label %compare_next5

next:                                             ; preds = %match_case
  br label %case_body

cond:                                             ; preds = %match_case
  br label %case_body2

match_case4:                                      ; preds = %compare_next
  br i1 true, label %cond7, label %next6

; [...]

cond7:                                            ; preds = %match_case4
  br label %case_body1

; [...]
}
```